# Can't get animation to work on arm rig

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I changed my model a bit and that probably made some changes to my rig. Now i cant get my armature to work with the mesh anymore. I've tries re-parenting but that changes the position of the mesh and animations dont even play. I can't figure out how to fix it, but maybe you can. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cTYXrOJ4nMfqTTUetG0VrBZn9pNrSHeK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you removed the armature modifier on your mesh.[image: armature modifier]

The armbands don't follow the armature because you haven't set a vertex group on them yet.